# Trying to add ALT tag within popup lightbox Lightbox2 for ADA Compliance Standards

Tags: javascript, accessibility, lightbox2, wcag, alt-attribute

I am updating a client's site to include alt tags to bring their site to ADA compliance. I have a few pages that use Lightbox2 from https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2. I added the ALT attribute to my array, but it's not being called in the script, so didn't get added.

`<a href="images/slide-show/at-the-beach-boys.jpg" title="An easy walk to fun at Long Sands Beach." alt="Small boys use sand toys on Long Sands Beach." rel="lightbox[Overview]"><img src="images/slide-show/at-the-beach-boys-th.jpg" alt="Small boys use sand toys on Long Sands Beach." width="256" height="176" /></a>`

I have tried to edit the lightbox.js to include the alt tag call, but have not been successful.

Contents of lightbox.js

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  Lightbox v2.03.3
//  by Lokesh Dhakar - http://www.huddletogether.com
//  5/21/06
//
//  For more information on this script, visit:
//  http://huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/
//
//  Licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 License - http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/
//  
//  Credit also due to those who have helped, inspired, and made their code available to the public.
//  Including: Scott Upton(uptonic.com), Peter-Paul Koch(quirksmode.com), Thomas Fuchs(mir.aculo.us), and others.
//
//
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*

    Table of Contents
    -----------------
    Configuration
    Global Variables

    Extending Built-in Objects  
    - Object.extend(Element)
    - Array.prototype.removeDuplicates()
    - Array.prototype.empty()

    Lightbox Class Declaration
    - initialize()
    - updateImageList()
    - start()
    - changeImage()
    - resizeImageContainer()
    - showImage()
    - updateDetails()
    - updateNav()
    - enableKeyboardNav()
    - disableKeyboardNav()
    - keyboardAction()
    - preloadNeighborImages()
    - end()

    Miscellaneous Functions
    - getPageScroll()
    - getPageSize()
    - getKey()
    - listenKey()
    - showSelectBoxes()
    - hideSelectBoxes()
    - showFlash()
    - hideFlash()
    - pause()
    - initLightbox()

    Function Calls
    - addLoadEvent(initLightbox)

*/
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//
//  Configuration
//
var fileLoadingImage = "../lightbox_assets/images/loading.gif";     
var fileBottomNavCloseImage = "../lightbox_assets/images/closelabel.gif";
var overlayOpacity = 0.8;   // controls transparency of shadow overlay

var animate = true;         // toggles resizing animations
var resizeSpeed = 7;        // controls the speed of the image resizing animations (1=slowest and 10=fastest)

var borderSize = 10;        //if you adjust the padding in the CSS, you will need to update this variable

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//
//  Global Variables
//
var imageArray = new Array;
var activeImage;

if(animate == true){
    overlayDuration = 0.2;  // shadow fade in/out duration
    if(resizeSpeed > 10){ resizeSpeed = 10;}
    if(resizeSpeed < 1){ resizeSpeed = 1;}
    resizeDuration = (11 - resizeSpeed) * 0.15;
} else { 
    overlayDuration = 0;
    resizeDuration = 0;
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//
//  Additional methods for Element added by SU, Couloir
//  - further additions by Lokesh Dhakar (huddletogether.com)
//
Object.extend(Element, {
    getWidth: function(element) {
        element = $(element);
        return element.offsetWidth; 
    },
    setWidth: function(element,w) {
        element = $(element);
        element.style.width = w +"px";
    },
    setHeight: function(element,h) {
        element = $(element);
        element.style.height = h +"px";
    },
    setTop: function(element,t) {
        element = $(element);
        element.style.top = t +"px";
    },
    setLeft: function(element,l) {
        element = $(element);
        element.style.left = l +"px";
    },
    setSrc: function(element,src) {
        element = $(element);
        element.src = src; 
    },
    setHref: function(element,href) {
        element = $(element);
        element.href = href; 
    },
    setInnerHTML: function(element,content) {
        element = $(element);
        element.innerHTML = content;
    }
});

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//
//  Extending built-in Array object
//  - array.removeDuplicates()
//  - array.empty()
//
Array.prototype.removeDuplicates = function () {
    for(i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
        for(j = this.length-1; j>i; j--){        
            if(this[i][0] == this[j][0]){
                this.splice(j,1);
            }
        }
    }
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Array.prototype.empty = function () {
    for(i = 0; i <= this.length; i++){
        this.shift();
    }
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//
//  Lightbox Class Declaration
//  - initialize()
//  - start()
//  - changeImage()
//  - resizeImageContainer()
//  - showImage()
//  - updateDetails()
//  - updateNav()
//  - enableKeyboardNav()
//  - disableKeyboardNav()
//  - keyboardNavAction()
//  - preloadNeighborImages()
//  - end()
//
//  Structuring of code inspired by Scott Upton (http://www.uptonic.com/)
//
var Lightbox = Class.create();

Lightbox.prototype = {

    // initialize()
    // Constructor runs on completion of the DOM loading. Calls updateImageList and then
    // the function inserts html at the bottom of the page which is used to display the shadow 
    // overlay and the image container.
    //
    initialize: function() {    

        this.updateImageList();

        // Code inserts html at the bottom of the page that looks similar to this:
        //
        //  <div id="overlay"></div>
        //  <div id="lightbox">
        //      <div id="outerImageContainer">
        //          <div id="imageContainer">
        //              <img id="lightboxImage" alt="container for enlarged images">
        //              <div style="" id="hoverNav">
        //                  <a href="#" id="prevLink"></a>
        //                  <a href="#" id="nextLink"></a>
        //              </div>
        //              <div id="loading">
        //                  <a href="#" id="loadingLink">
        //                      <img src="images/loading.gif" alt"Waiting to load">
        //                  </a>
        //              </div>
        //          </div>
        //      </div>
        //      <div id="imageDataContainer">
        //          <div id="imageData">
        //              <div id="imageDetails">
        //                  <span id="caption"></span>
        //                  <span id="numberDisplay"></span>
        //              </div>
        //              <div id="bottomNav">
        //                  <a href="#" id="bottomNavClose">
        //                      <img src="../images/close.gif" alt="X graphic to close lightbox">
        //                  </a>
        //              </div>
        //          </div>
        //      </div>
        //  </div>


        var objBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0);

        var objOverlay = document.createElement("div");
        objOverlay.setAttribute('id','overlay');
        objOverlay.style.display = 'none';
        objOverlay.onclick = function() { myLightbox.end(); }
        objBody.appendChild(objOverlay);

        var objLightbox = document.createElement("div");
        objLightbox.setAttribute('id','lightbox');
        objLightbox.style.display = 'none';
        objLightbox.onclick = function(e) { // close Lightbox is user clicks shadow overlay
            if (!e) var e = window.event;
            var clickObj = Event.element(e).id;
            if ( clickObj == 'lightbox') {
                myLightbox.end();
            }
        };
        objBody.appendChild(objLightbox);

        var objOuterImageContainer = document.createElement("div");
        objOuterImageContainer.setAttribute('id','outerImageContainer');
        objLightbox.appendChild(objOuterImageContainer);

        // When Lightbox starts it will resize itself from 250 by 250 to the current image dimension.
        // If animations are turned off, it will be hidden as to prevent a flicker of a
        // white 250 by 250 box.
        if(animate){
            Element.setWidth('outerImageContainer', 250);
            Element.setHeight('outerImageContainer', 250);          
        } else {
            Element.setWidth('outerImageContainer', 1);
            Element.setHeight('outerImageContainer', 1);            
        }

        var objImageContainer = document.createElement("div");
        objImageContainer.setAttribute('id','imageContainer');
        objOuterImageContainer.appendChild(objImageContainer);

        var objLightboxImage = document.createElement("img");
        objLightboxImage.setAttribute('id','lightboxImage');
        objImageContainer.appendChild(objLightboxImage);

        var objHoverNav = document.createElement("div");
        objHoverNav.setAttribute('id','hoverNav');
        objImageContainer.appendChild(objHoverNav);

        var objPrevLink = document.createElement("a");
        objPrevLink.setAttribute('id','prevLink');
        objPrevLink.setAttribute('href','#');
        objHoverNav.appendChild(objPrevLink);

        var objNextLink = document.createElement("a");
        objNextLink.setAttribute('id','nextLink');
        objNextLink.setAttribute('href','#');
        objHoverNav.appendChild(objNextLink);

        var objLoading = document.createElement("div");
        objLoading.setAttribute('id','loading');
        objImageContainer.appendChild(objLoading);

        var objLoadingLink = document.createElement("a");
        objLoadingLink.setAttribute('id','loadingLink');
        objLoadingLink.setAttribute('href','#');
        objLoadingLink.onclick = function() { myLightbox.end(); return false; }
        objLoading.appendChild(objLoadingLink);

        var objLoadingImage = document.createElement("img");
        objLoadingImage.setAttribute('src', fileLoadingImage);
        objLoadingImage.setAttribute('alt', 'Image Loading icon');
        objLoadingLink.appendChild(objLoadingImage);

        var objImageDataContainer = document.createElement("div");
        objImageDataContainer.setAttribute('id','imageDataContainer');
        objLightbox.appendChild(objImageDataContainer);

        var objImageData = document.createElement("div");
        objImageData.setAttribute('id','imageData');
        objImageDataContainer.appendChild(objImageData);

        var objImageDetails = document.createElement("div");
        objImageDetails.setAttribute('id','imageDetails');
        objImageData.appendChild(objImageDetails);

        var objCaption = document.createElement("span");
        objCaption.setAttribute('id','caption');
        objImageDetails.appendChild(objCaption);

        var objNumberDisplay = document.createElement("span");
        objNumberDisplay.setAttribute('id','numberDisplay');
        objImageDetails.appendChild(objNumberDisplay);

        var objBottomNav = document.createElement("div");
        objBottomNav.setAttribute('id','bottomNav');
        objImageData.appendChild(objBottomNav);

        var objBottomNavCloseLink = document.createElement("a");
        objBottomNavCloseLink.setAttribute('id','bottomNavClose');
        objBottomNavCloseLink.setAttribute('href','#');
        objBottomNavCloseLink.onclick = function() { myLightbox.end(); return false; }
        objBottomNav.appendChild(objBottomNavCloseLink);

        var objBottomNavCloseImage = document.createElement("img");
        objBottomNavCloseImage.setAttribute('src', fileBottomNavCloseImage);
        objBottomNavCloseImage.setAttribute('alt', 'CLOSE X');
        objBottomNavCloseLink.appendChild(objBottomNavCloseImage);
    },


    //
    // updateImageList()
    // Loops through anchor tags looking for 'lightbox' references and applies onclick
    // events to appropriate links. You can rerun after dynamically adding images w/ajax.
    //
    updateImageList: function() {   
        if (!document.getElementsByTagName){ return; }
        var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        var areas = document.getElementsByTagName('area');

        // loop through all anchor tags
        for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++){
            var anchor = anchors[i];

            var relAttribute = String(anchor.getAttribute('rel'));

            // use the string.match() method to catch 'lightbox' references in the rel attribute
            if (anchor.getAttribute('href') && (relAttribute.toLowerCase().match('lightbox'))){
                anchor.onclick = function () {myLightbox.start(this); return false;}
            }
        }

        // loop through all area tags
        // todo: combine anchor & area tag loops
        for (var i=0; i< areas.length; i++){
            var area = areas[i];

            var relAttribute = String(area.getAttribute('rel'));

            // use the string.match() method to catch 'lightbox' references in the rel attribute
            if (area.getAttribute('href') && (relAttribute.toLowerCase().match('lightbox'))){
                area.onclick = function () {myLightbox.start(this); return false;}
            }
        }
    },


    //
    //  start()
    //  Display overlay and lightbox. If image is part of a set, add siblings to imageArray.
    //
    start: function(imageLink) {    

        hideSelectBoxes();
        hideFlash();

        // stretch overlay to fill page and fade in
        var arrayPageSize = getPageSize();
        Element.setWidth('overlay', arrayPageSize[0]);
        Element.setHeight('overlay', arrayPageSize[1]);

        new Effect.Appear('overlay', { duration: overlayDuration, from: 0.0, to: overlayOpacity });

        imageArray = [];
        imageNum = 0;       

        if (!document.getElementsByTagName){ return; }
        var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName( imageLink.tagName);

        // if image is NOT part of a set..
        if((imageLink.getAttribute('rel') == 'lightbox')){
            // add single image to imageArray
            imageArray.push(new Array(imageLink.getAttribute('href'), imageLink.getAttribute('title')));            
        } else {
        // if image is part of a set..

            // loop through anchors, find other images in set, and add them to imageArray
            for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++){
                var anchor = anchors[i];
                if (anchor.getAttribute('href') && (anchor.getAttribute('rel') == imageLink.getAttribute('rel'))){
                    imageArray.push(new Array(anchor.getAttribute('href'), anchor.getAttribute('title')));
                }
            }
            imageArray.removeDuplicates();
            while(imageArray[imageNum][0] != imageLink.getAttribute('href')) { imageNum++;}
        }

        // calculate top and left offset for the lightbox 
        var arrayPageScroll = getPageScroll();
        var lightboxTop = arrayPageScroll[1] + (arrayPageSize[3] / 10);
        var lightboxLeft = arrayPageScroll[0];
        Element.setTop('lightbox', lightboxTop);
        Element.setLeft('lightbox', lightboxLeft);

        Element.show('lightbox');

        this.changeImage(imageNum);
    },

    //
    //  changeImage()
    //  Hide most elements and preload image in preparation for resizing image container.
    //
    changeImage: function(imageNum) {   

        activeImage = imageNum; // update global var

        // hide elements during transition
        if(animate){ Element.show('loading');}
        Element.hide('lightboxImage');
        Element.hide('alt');
        Element.hide('hoverNav');
        Element.hide('prevLink');
        Element.hide('nextLink');
        Element.hide('imageDataContainer');
        Element.hide('numberDisplay');      

        imgPreloader = new Image();

        // once image is preloaded, resize image container
        imgPreloader.onload=function(){
            Element.setSrc('lightboxImage', imageArray[activeImage][0]);
            myLightbox.resizeImageContainer(imgPreloader.width, imgPreloader.height);

            imgPreloader.onload=function(){};   //  clear onLoad, IE behaves irratically with animated gifs otherwise 
        }
        imgPreloader.src = imageArray[activeImage][0];
    },

    //
    //  resizeImageContainer()
    //
    resizeImageContainer: function( imgWidth, imgHeight) {

        // get curren width and height
        this.widthCurrent = Element.getWidth('outerImageContainer');
        this.heightCurrent = Element.getHeight('outerImageContainer');

        // get new width and height
        var widthNew = (imgWidth  + (borderSize * 2));
        var heightNew = (imgHeight  + (borderSize * 2));

        // scalars based on change from old to new
        this.xScale = ( widthNew / this.widthCurrent) * 100;
        this.yScale = ( heightNew / this.heightCurrent) * 100;

        // calculate size difference between new and old image, and resize if necessary
        wDiff = this.widthCurrent - widthNew;
        hDiff = this.heightCurrent - heightNew;

        if(!( hDiff == 0)){ new Effect.Scale('outerImageContainer', this.yScale, {scaleX: false, duration: resizeDuration, queue: 'front'}); }
        if(!( wDiff == 0)){ new Effect.Scale('outerImageContainer', this.xScale, {scaleY: false, delay: resizeDuration, duration: resizeDuration}); }

        // if new and old image are same size and no scaling transition is necessary, 
        // do a quick pause to prevent image flicker.
        if((hDiff == 0) && (wDiff == 0)){
            if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE")!=-1){ pause(250); } else { pause(100);} 
        }

        Element.setHeight('prevLink', imgHeight);
        Element.setHeight('nextLink', imgHeight);
        Element.setWidth( 'imageDataContainer', widthNew);

        this.showImage();
    },

    //
    //  showImage()
    //  Display image and begin preloading neighbors.
    //
    showImage: function(){
        Element.hide('loading');
        new Effect.Appear('lightboxImage', { duration: resizeDuration, queue: 'end', afterFinish: function(){   myLightbox.updateDetails(); } });
        this.preloadNeighborImages();
    },

    //
    //  updateDetails()
    //  Display caption, image number, and bottom nav.
    //
    updateDetails: function() {

        // if caption is not null
        if(imageArray[activeImage][1]){
            Element.show('caption');
            Element.setInnerHTML( 'caption', imageArray[activeImage][1]);
        }

        // if image is part of set display 'Image x of x' 
        if(imageArray.length > 1){
            Element.show('numberDisplay');
            Element.setInnerHTML( 'numberDisplay', "Image " + eval(activeImage + 1) + " of " + imageArray.length);
        }

        new Effect.Parallel(
            [ new Effect.SlideDown( 'imageDataContainer', { sync: true, duration: resizeDuration, from: 0.0, to: 1.0 }), 
              new Effect.Appear('imageDataContainer', { sync: true, duration: resizeDuration }) ], 
            { duration: resizeDuration, afterFinish: function() {
                // update overlay size and update nav
                var arrayPageSize = getPageSize();
                Element.setHeight('overlay', arrayPageSize[1]);
                myLightbox.updateNav();
                }
            } 
        );
    },

    //
    //  updateNav()
    //  Display appropriate previous and next hover navigation.
    //
    updateNav: function() {

        Element.show('hoverNav');               

        // if not first image in set, display prev image button
        if(activeImage != 0){
            Element.show('prevLink');
            document.getElementById('prevLink').onclick = function() {
                myLightbox.changeImage(activeImage - 1); return false;
            }
        }

        // if not last image in set, display next image button
        if(activeImage != (imageArray.length - 1)){
            Element.show('nextLink');
            document.getElementById('nextLink').onclick = function() {
                myLightbox.changeImage(activeImage + 1); return false;
            }
        }

        this.enableKeyboardNav();
    },

    //
    //  enableKeyboardNav()
    //
    enableKeyboardNav: function() {
        document.onkeydown = this.keyboardAction; 
    },

    //
    //  disableKeyboardNav()
    //
    disableKeyboardNav: function() {
        document.onkeydown = '';
    },

    //
    //  keyboardAction()
    //
    keyboardAction: function(e) {
        if (e == null) { // ie
            keycode = event.keyCode;
            escapeKey = 27;
        } else { // mozilla
            keycode = e.keyCode;
            escapeKey = e.DOM_VK_ESCAPE;
        }

        key = String.fromCharCode(keycode).toLowerCase();

        if((key == 'x') || (key == 'o') || (key == 'c') || (keycode == escapeKey)){ // close lightbox
            myLightbox.end();
        } else if((key == 'p') || (keycode == 37)){ // display previous image
            if(activeImage != 0){
                myLightbox.disableKeyboardNav();
                myLightbox.changeImage(activeImage - 1);
            }
        } else if((key == 'n') || (keycode == 39)){ // display next image
            if(activeImage != (imageArray.length - 1)){
                myLightbox.disableKeyboardNav();
                myLightbox.changeImage(activeImage + 1);
            }
        }

    },

    //
    //  preloadNeighborImages()
    //  Preload previous and next images.
    //
    preloadNeighborImages: function(){

        if((imageArray.length - 1) > activeImage){
            preloadNextImage = new Image();
            preloadNextImage.src = imageArray[activeImage + 1][0];
        }
        if(activeImage > 0){
            preloadPrevImage = new Image();
            preloadPrevImage.src = imageArray[activeImage - 1][0];
        }

    },

    //
    //  end()
    //
    end: function() {
        this.disableKeyboardNav();
        Element.hide('lightbox');
        new Effect.Fade('overlay', { duration: overlayDuration});
        showSelectBoxes();
        showFlash();
    }
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//
// getPageScroll()
// Returns array with x,y page scroll values.
// Core code from - quirksmode.com
//
function getPageScroll(){

    var xScroll, yScroll;

    if (self.pageYOffset) {
        yScroll = self.pageYOffset;
        xScroll = self.pageXOffset;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop){  // Explorer 6 Strict
        yScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        xScroll = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    } else if (document.body) {// all other Explorers
        yScroll = document.body.scrollTop;
        xScroll = document.body.scrollLeft; 
    }

    arrayPageScroll = new Array(xScroll,yScroll) 
    return arrayPageScroll;
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//
// getPageSize()
// Returns array with page width, height and window width, height
// Core code from - quirksmode.com
// Edit for Firefox by pHaez
//
function getPageSize(){

    var xScroll, yScroll;

    if (window.innerHeight && window.scrollMaxY) {  
        xScroll = window.innerWidth + window.scrollMaxX;
        yScroll = window.innerHeight + window.scrollMaxY;
    } else if (document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.offsetHeight){ // all but Explorer Mac
        xScroll = document.body.scrollWidth;
        yScroll = document.body.scrollHeight;
    } else { // Explorer Mac...would also work in Explorer 6 Strict, Mozilla and Safari
        xScroll = document.body.offsetWidth;
        yScroll = document.body.offsetHeight;
    }

    var windowWidth, windowHeight;

//  console.log(self.innerWidth);
//  console.log(document.documentElement.clientWidth);

    if (self.innerHeight) { // all except Explorer
        if(document.documentElement.clientWidth){
            windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth; 
        } else {
            windowWidth = self.innerWidth;
        }
        windowHeight = self.innerHeight;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) { // Explorer 6 Strict Mode
        windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    } else if (document.body) { // other Explorers
        windowWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
        windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    }   

    // for small pages with total height less then height of the viewport
    if(yScroll < windowHeight){
        pageHeight = windowHeight;
    } else { 
        pageHeight = yScroll;
    }

//  console.log("xScroll " + xScroll)
//  console.log("windowWidth " + windowWidth)

    // for small pages with total width less then width of the viewport
    if(xScroll < windowWidth){  
        pageWidth = xScroll;        
    } else {
        pageWidth = windowWidth;
    }
//  console.log("pageWidth " + pageWidth)

    arrayPageSize = new Array(pageWidth,pageHeight,windowWidth,windowHeight) 
    return arrayPageSize;
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//
// getKey(key)
// Gets keycode. If 'x' is pressed then it hides the lightbox.
//
function getKey(e){
    if (e == null) { // ie
        keycode = event.keyCode;
    } else { // mozilla
        keycode = e.which;
    }
    key = String.fromCharCode(keycode).toLowerCase();

    if(key == 'x'){
    }
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//
// listenKey()
//
function listenKey () { document.onkeypress = getKey; }

// ---------------------------------------------------

function showSelectBoxes(){
    var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for (i = 0; i != selects.length; i++) {
        selects[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}

// ---------------------------------------------------

function hideSelectBoxes(){
    var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for (i = 0; i != selects.length; i++) {
        selects[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}

// ---------------------------------------------------

function showFlash(){
    var flashObjects = document.getElementsByTagName("object");
    for (i = 0; i < flashObjects.length; i++) {
        flashObjects[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    var flashEmbeds = document.getElementsByTagName("embed");
    for (i = 0; i < flashEmbeds.length; i++) {
        flashEmbeds[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}

// ---------------------------------------------------

function hideFlash(){
    var flashObjects = document.getElementsByTagName("object");
    for (i = 0; i < flashObjects.length; i++) {
        flashObjects[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    var flashEmbeds = document.getElementsByTagName("embed");
    for (i = 0; i < flashEmbeds.length; i++) {
        flashEmbeds[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

}


// ---------------------------------------------------

//
// pause(numberMillis)
// Pauses code execution for specified time. Uses busy code, not good.
// Help from Ran Bar-On [ran2103@gmail.com]
//

function pause(ms){
    var date = new Date();
    curDate = null;
    do{var curDate = new Date();}
    while( curDate - date < ms);
}
/*
function pause(numberMillis) {
    var curently = new Date().getTime() + sender;
    while (new Date().getTime();    
}
*/
// ---------------------------------------------------



function initLightbox() { myLightbox = new Lightbox(); }
//Event.observe(window, 'load', initLightbox, false);
```

Comment: href is linking to an image. How can that be ADA compliant? (oh and there is a newer version of lightbox 2, namely 2.04, just FYI)

Answer (score 0):

I've continued to work on this and have a temporary solution until the mainframe of Lightbox2 has a working alt tag on the overlay (tried up to current version 11.1 but they weren't working). I added a setAlt section after line 122

```
    setAlt: function(element,alt) {
        element = $(element);
        element.alt = alt; 
    },
```

and  then added the alt call in the image preloader section (around line 440). I tried calling a value for the ALT in this code, but best I could get was 'undefined', so I've set a static value.

```
        imgPreloader = new Image();

        // once image is preloaded, resize image container
        imgPreloader.onload=function(){
            Element.setSrc('lightboxImage', imageArray[activeImage][0]);
            Element.setAlt('lightboxImage', 'Caption below');
               // Element.setAlt ('lightboxImage', imageArray[activeImage][0].alt); 
               //which returned alt="undefined". Couldn't figure out setting VAR
            myLightbox.resizeImageContainer(imgPreloader.width, imgPreloader.height);
```